# Map a function over a list for each argument

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm looking for some attractive Haskell syntax for the following

I have a function that takes 4 argument.

f a b c d = Something

I'd like to supply a lists for each of the arguments and get back the a list of the results of each combination.

Essentially a nested map function.

I fell like there should be an elegant solution. But, I haven't found anything that will compile.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Please can you show some example input and output?

Comment: Can you rephrase? Are you looking for zip4? Or zipWith4? What would be the type of the function you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not very clear: do you want all possible combinations (take any `a` from the first list, any `b` from the second etc.) or processing lists in parallel a.k.a. zip (the first element of each list, the second element and so on).

Both can be nicely solved with applicative functors:

```
Prelude> let f a b c d = (a,b,c,d)
Prelude Control.Applicative> :m +Control.Applicative 
Prelude Control.Applicative> f <$> [1,2] <*> [3,4] <*> [5,6] <*> [7,8]
[(1,3,5,7),(1,3,5,8),(1,3,6,7),(1,3,6,8),(1,4,5,7),(1,4,5,8),(1,4,6,7),(1,4,6,8),(2,3,5,7),(2,3,5,8),(2,3,6,7),(2,3,6,8),(2,4,5,7),(2,4,5,8),(2,4,6,7),(2,4,6,8)]
Prelude Control.Applicative> getZipList $ f <$> ZipList [1,2] <*> ZipList [3,4] <*> ZipList [5,6] <*> ZipList [7,8]
[(1,3,5,7),(2,4,6,8)]
```

Comment: Also see http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/she/idiom.html when it comes to plain syntax.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the first of these, which happens to be my favorite usage of the List applicative instance.

Comment: second option has a plain function: zipWith4 f [1,2] [3,4] [5,6] [7,8]

Comment: What I don't like about zipWith4 is that it doesn't give me all possible combinations of arguments. It gives me f 1 3 5 7 and f 2 4 5 6

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are looking for:

> fourway f as bs cs ds = map (curry4 f)
>   [(r,s,t,u) | r <- as, s <- bs, t <-
>   cs, u <- ds]
>     **where** curry4 f (a,b,c,d) = f a b c d

You could do this point free and be cuter but I think this is what you want and is easier to read.